# Publish Subscribe Pattern using .asmx

Tags: c#, web-services, mono, publish-subscribe

Is it possible to implement a publish-subscribe model using Web Services (not WCF).

I ask because I need to use Mono, which has an incomplete WCF implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply said, NO this is not possible. You have to use duplex communication only using WCF:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx

This feature is exclusive to WCF. Is there any possibility of using Sockets? asmx won't support this type of communication.